# Cannot Create React Native Project with Yarn

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

When I enable corepack (means enable yarn) and try to create a project `npx react-native init MyTestProject` I'm getting the following error,

[image]

But when I use `npm` by disabling yarn project creating successfully.